# Get Rank from two Ranks

Tags: analysis

i'm a math-noob and looking for a way to get the rank of two ranks.

For example

1. 26939 customers total
2. Rank 1 is 10 from total volume of sales grouped by each customer
3. Rank 2 is 470 from total numbers of sales grouped by each customer

How to get the rank of those two ranks?

Comment: What does this mean -- "first rank" and "second rank"?

Comment: I determine two ranks of an entry by different ways. Now i want combine these into one rank.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you determine the first and the second rank exactly, and how would you like to combine them?

Comment: First rank is delivered by the total volume of sales, the second by the number of sales. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes. Writing the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have $n$ items, each of which has two different ranks, resulting in vectors $(a_k, b_k)_{k=1}^n$ which you would like to combine into one common ranking.

I suggest you do the following. Compute $c_k = (a_k + b_k)/2$ for each point (i.e. average the 2 ratings), and sort the points by the increasing $c_k$, and if the $c_k$ are the same, then sort by increasing $a_k$. This will give you a unique ordering, which you can now renumber.

E.g., consider the following rankings on 4 elements: 3,2,1,5,4 and 5,2,3,4,1. The rating average ie 4, 2, 2, 4.5, 2.5. So the sort would order them by the last set, and then by the first set. The resulting position order is 3,2,5,1,4.